# disable auto correct extjs6 datefield

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, datefield

I need to make a form containing several fields, including the one that is giving me trouble: the date field.

in itself, what it does is very good, but it doesn't comply with the requirement not to auto-correct and simply get an "invalid date" error.

the case in question is February 30, which automatically changes to March 2.

you can easily reproduce this example on the official api: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html

enter 02302022 and the blur will change to 03/02/2022

I tried to change the validator to refuse my input this way, but it doesn't work because the Ext.Date.parse function also corrects the date!

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Dates',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        name: 'from_date',
        
            validator: function (val) 
            {   
                // manual
                var man = Ext.Date.parse( val , 'mdY' ) != null ;
                //formated
                var formated = Ext.Date.parse( val , 'm/d/Y' ) != null ;
                return manual || formated;
            }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Would this work for you?

`validator: function (val) { var date = this.parseDate(val); if (!date) return 'Invalid date'; return this.Date.parse( val , 'mdY' ); },`

Comment: no, unfortunately it doesn't work
by slightly modifying your proposal, the component works again (the validator waits for a boolean true if date ok) but it doesn't solve my problem of the self-modified february 30th.

`            validator: function (val) 
            {   
               var date = this.parseDate(val); 
               if (!date) return 'Invalid date'; 
               return true; //this.Date.parse( val , 'mdY' ); 
            }
 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the "useStrict" setting to true so that the data is not automatically corrected.

[image]